# How do you create a multileveled list across tables, in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I achieve the following most efficiently, ideally with an automated feature which will generate X.1, X.2, X.3, etc... on each click?

In the following picture, I typed X.1, X.2 manually, where X = 1, 2. The green are boxes that I created manually.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use SEQ-fields. This is a test:

[image]

And this is the source:

[image]

The flag `\c` uses the current sequence value without incrementing it, the flag `\r` resets the sequence to the given value. The rest, I hope, is self-explaining.

To create a field, use `Ctrl+F9`. To switch the view between field codes and field results, use `Alt+F9`. The fields are not updated automatically. Update a field (or all the fields in a selection) using `F9`.

To automate insertion of fields, I recommend to create Quick Parts with them.